# xdotool window search failing randomly

Tags: linux

I am simply starting gedit and trying to find the gedit window using xdotool

`xdotool search "gedit"`

Some times it gives me a window ID, other times it fails with

```
X Error of failed request: 20(X_GetProperty)
Major opcode of failed request: 20 (X_GetProperty)
```

What could be the problem? I am accessing the machine on which I am running this setup through vncviewer.

Comment: It's 2019 and I've got the same problem. It finds a terminal (Terminator) window named 'CC' and then chokes when I change the name to 'CO'. Command is:  xdotool search --name CO windowactivate.  Get error: XGetWindowProperty[_NET_WM_DESKTOP] failed (code=1) I can't seem to isolate why its choking.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a property of what you are searching for:

`xdotool search --name "gedit"`